# how do I know how many pixels are being used when I use 100% width for the body tag

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I am trying to make a website with a fluid layout. So to do this I am trying to use percentages as measurements. If I am not mistaken, the percentages are calculated from the parent element. Since the html tags does not have any set width, how does the body tag calculate 100% width? does 100% means the full resolution of the screen that you are viewing the page?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [read the specs](http://alistapart.com/article/readspec) to find the answer to your question:

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#x3 says about percentage widths:

> **<percentage>**
> Specifies a percentage width. The percentage is
> calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's **containing
> block**.

About containing blocks:

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#containing-block-details says:

> The position and size of an element's box(es) are sometimes calculated
> relative to a certain rectangle, called the containing block of the
> element. The containing block of an element is defined as follows:
>
> The containing block in which the **root element** lives is a rectangle
> called the **initial containing block**. For **continuous media**, it has the
> dimensions of the **viewport** and is anchored at the **canvas** origin;
>
> (...)

The **root element** is <html> (https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/html.html).

The screen is considered a **continuous media**.

The relationship between **viewport** and **canvas** is simple:

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#viewport
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/intro.html#canvas

> User agents for continuous media generally offer users a **viewport** (**a
> window or other viewing area on the screen**) through which users
> consult a document. User agents may change the document's layout when
> the viewport is resized (see the initial containing block).
>
> When the viewport is smaller than the area of the canvas on which the
> document is rendered, the user agent should offer a scrolling
> mechanism.

So, trying to simplify this, the canvas size considers the content size even if it doesn't fit on the browser window.

The browser window contains the viewport (considered without menus, scrolling bar and status bar).

---

So, if `<body>` has 100% width, that means it would be the same width as the `<html>` element, which width is equal to the viewport's width.

You can easily find the viewport width by inspecting the css for `<html>` element on Chrome.

Comment: s o if I am trying to make a fluid layout and how do I know how much is 100% in resolution?

Comment: 100% (width) of `<body>` is the width of the viewport, the visible part of the page without scroll bars, and also the width of `<html>`. You can inspect the `<html>` e.g. in Chrome to get that value.

Comment: @aspire29 Did that help ? Feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

100% width for the `body` tag means 100% of the `html` width, which again is the full width of the *viewport*, which on desktops will be the browser window, on mobile devices the screen width.

Answer (score -1):

Using just HTML and CSS would not suffice to get the width, you would need to use Javascript, or even better, a framework like [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) that would help you get the body's width.

Using jquery the code would look something like this:

```
$(document).width();
```

You can find out more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/width/).